# asp.net: javascript function works when called from button click event, not when called from subscription event from redis

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, redis

i'm using the same js script call in both scenarios... one it is called from a button_click event and it works properly (changes the label text) as per below...

```
public void Test_OnClientClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "updateText", "updateText('test');", true);
        }
```

When it is called from an event raised by a redis subscription, the same call does not work...

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Establish connection
        redisConn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisIP);
        rbsub = redisConn.GetSubscriber();
        rbsub.Subscribe(ServerRedisChannel).OnMessage(channelMessage => {
            MessageHandler(channelMessage.Message.ToString());
        });

    }


    public void MessageHandler(string cm)
    {
        try
        {
            //Test_OnClientClick(null, null);
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "updateText", "updateText('test');", true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var x = e;
        }
    }
```

I confirm it reaches the ClientScript call in MessageHandler with a breakpoint but it never reaches the debugger in the js script.

Full code below:

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Async="true" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebForm._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">

    function updateText(strData) {
        debugger;
        document.getElementById("<%=lblTest.ClientID%>").innerHTML = strData;
    }

</script> 

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>redis test</h1>

        <p><asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text="redis output"></asp:Label></p>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Test_OnClientClick"/>

        <p><a href="http://www.asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>



</asp:Content>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using StackExchange.Redis;


namespace WebForm
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        ConnectionMultiplexer redisConn;
        ISubscriber rbsub;
        public const string redisIP = "gptdevnj01:6379";
        public const string ServerRedisChannel = "ac"; 
        public const int redisDB = 7;


        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Establish connection
            redisConn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisIP);
            rbsub = redisConn.GetSubscriber();
            rbsub.Subscribe(ServerRedisChannel).OnMessage(channelMessage => {
                MessageHandler(channelMessage.Message.ToString());
            });

        }


        public void MessageHandler(string cm)
        {
            try
            {
                //Test_OnClientClick(null, null);
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "updateText", "updateText('test');", true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var x = e;
            }
        }
        public void Test_OnClientClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "updateText", "updateText('test');", true);
        }


    }
}
```

So i suppose the question boils down to calling a js script from a button_click event differs from when it is called from a subscription (or async) event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response to a button click happens within [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178472(v=vs.140)), whereas handling of an asynchronous message from a Redis subscription will most likely:

1. happen completely outside of that lifecycle, and
2. in a completely different thread.

Unless you synchronize those threads somehow (one that handles the request and one that handles received messages) - your call to `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` will go to void, to wrong client or simply fail. Please note however that the nature of asynchronous operations may require a different approach from your side rather blocking a thread to wait for a message.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's the path i'm researching...how to handle the Redis subscription event to allow it to update the webpage...  any thoughts?  Do I need SignalR or similar?  Please bear in mind, the button is just for testing, the messagehandler should update the webpage

Comment: Yes, using WebSockets is one of options, but as usual the answer is "it depends". And it depends on user requirements/expectations.

Comment: That confirmed my suspicion to continue on the SignalR path so I will mark this as answered, thank you @tomasz